# Serenity Report Dashboard

Tags: java, maven, serenity-bdd

Im using serenity framework to do automation testing. My problem is the generated HTML report is separate to two files - One for Firefox and another one for Chrome due to i have two Test Manager class.

Questions: 
1. How to create a nicely dashboard report similar to Extent or Allure?

Current Report looks like this: 
[image]

Better Report: 
[image]

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To generate the full Serenity report you need to run `mvn serenity:aggregate` or `gradle aggregate`. You can use the `maven-serenity-plugin` to integrate it into the `mvn verify` stage:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${serenity.maven.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                  <tags>${tags}</tags>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>serenity-reports</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```